# Specific Question about $\omega_1$ hierarchies

Tags: set-theory, computability

Consider a $\omega_1$ hierarchy of increasing functions such that whenever we have $\alpha<\beta$, we get $f_\alpha < f_\beta$. The $<$ symbol denotes (eventual) domination.

All functions below are from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Now consider the following propositions/statements:

$(p)$ There is no function $F$ such that $F>f_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$. **Edit:**(as was pointed out in the answer a stronger condition was intended here. And that was that for any function $F$ there must exist some $\alpha<\omega_1$ so that $f_\alpha > F$ **End**

$(q)$ $\mathbb{R}$ can be well-ordered (I don't have enough understanding here, but just in case this doesn't suffice, then possibly a more powerful(?) assumption such as AC can be assumed)

$(r)$ CH is true

Now is it true that the truth of $p$ and $q$ implies $r$?

If the above is false, then there is one way it seems possible to me. Consider some arbitrary function $r:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. And now denote $A_r$ as set of all those increasing functions $g$ such that $g \le_T r$. But now there must exist some $p<\omega_1$ such that $f_p > A_r$ (meaning $f_p$ dominates every function in the collection $A_r$) and yet $r \nleq_T f_p$. And neither is $r$ computationally reducible to any function (in the given hierarchy) that dominates $f_p$.

Is the reading in above paragraph correct or incorrect. If it is incorrect, then where does the error lie? And in case it is correct, can one give example of such a function $r$?

Comment: The conjunction of $p$ and $q$ does not imply $r$. Your statement $p$ is what in the theory of [cardinal characteristics of the continuum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288483/6085) is denoted by $\mathfrak d=\omega_1$. It is consistent that choice holds, $\mathfrak d=\omega_1$, and the continuum is arbitrarily large. See for instance [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your previous to last paragraph is saying. Is this a statement suggested as a replacement for $(p\land q)$ that you hope implies CH? Is it a way in which you expect that $(p\land q)$ will hold while CH fails? Are you saying that you expect that there is such a function $f_p$, no matter what $r$ is?

Comment: I was asking whether there is "some" $r$ which has this property?  The property that there exists a function $f_p$ so that $f_p>A_r$, and with access to $f_p$ one can't compute $r$. And, given the comments below the answer, it seems that there are such $r$'s.

Comment: "Is it a way in which you expect that $(p \land q)$ will hold while CH fails? " Yes exactly!! Just quoting this because it might help someone reading the question understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Let's dispense with your $(q)$ by working in ZFC (so everything can be well-ordered). Also, "function" will mean "function from $\omega$ to $\omega$."*

The existence of a family $F$ of the type you describe is implied by $\mathfrak{d}=\omega_1$, where $\mathfrak{d}$ is the **dominating number**: the minimal cardinality of any set of functions such that every function is dominated by one in the set. This is not too hard: given any sequence $D=(g_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1}$ of $\omega_1$-many functions, we can construct a sequence of functions $(f_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1}$ such that $f_\eta>f_\beta+g_\beta$ for every $\beta<\eta<\omega_1$; now just let $D$ be a dominating family of size $\omega_1$.

The equality $\mathfrak{d}=\omega_1$ is strictly weaker than CH, so in fact $(p)$ and $(q)$ together do not imply $(r)$.

---

So what about your analysis? (Fix such an $F$ and assume $(q)$ but $\neg(r)$.)

*Incidentally, note that the only thing you're using about Turing reducibility is that there are only countably many functions Turing reducible to a given one. That doesn't play a direct role, but removing the computability-theoretic aspects - until they become necessary, if ever - will make things less mysterious.*

Your claim that there is some $f_p$ dominating every function computable from a fixed real $r$ is **not justified** unless we assume a stronger hypothesis on $F$: namely, that every function is dominated (not merely escaped) by some function in $F$. This is still consistent with $\neg$CH, though, so let's assume it. It *does* of course justify the existence of an $f_p$ dominating every $r$-computable function.

However, you then claim

> And neither is $r$ computationally reducible to any function (in the given hierarchy) that dominates $f_p$.

This will be false in general (what if $r$ is computable?). What is true is that no function dominating $f_p$ (in the given hierarchy or not) is $\le_Tr$, but that's the opposite of what you've written. However, if CH fails then what you've written will *sometimes* be true: there are only $\omega_1$-many reals Turing reducible to some function in $F$, so (assuming $\neg$CH) there will be some real $r$ which is not Turing reducible to any of the functions in $F$ at all.

> Proof: The set of functions computable relative to some $f\in F$ has cardinality $\omega_1\cdot\omega=\omega_1$ (since only countably many things are computable in a given function, and there are $\omega_1$-many functions in $F$). So since CH fails, we can find some $r$ not computable from any member of $F$. Indeed, this means that most reals will not be computable from any member in $F$.

I think this is what you actually mean, given your question "And in case it is correct, can one give example of such a function $r$?" So perhaps this is a typo rather than a genuine error. To that question, the answer is that practically any $r$ can have this property. Perhaps counterintuitively, if $\mathfrak{d}=\omega_1$, there is lots of flexibility in constructing the family $F$, and for almost any $r$ we can construct an appropriate $F$. Precisely:

> Assume $\mathfrak{d}=\omega_1$. The following are equivalent: $(i)$ $r$ is not hyperarithmetic. $(ii)$ There is a dominating family $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ such that $f_\alpha<f_\beta$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$ *and* $r$ is not Turing reducible to any of the $f_\alpha$s.

The proof is a bit technical, but is basically an iterated *limited* forcing argument. ("Limited" in the sense that we're not performing full forcing, but rather just building a "sufficiently generic" object inside our set-theoretic universe.) It's a small tweak on a theorem of Solovay, that the reals computable from fast-enough growing functions are precisely the hyperarithmetic reals.

Comment: Before I read what you have written in detail, just one specific point. What I was trying to say was (I will check the wording of my question more carefully later on) that if you have, say, $r$ as a computable function, and $A_r$ as the set of all increasing functions that can be computed (given a program with oracle for $r$) ........ then in that case can you give an example of a function $f_p$ that dominates every function in $A_r$ and yet with an oracle access to $f_p$, one can't compute $r$. Similarly replace $r$ with halting problem, or for that matter, any other function.

Comment: @SSequence Well, that's false: $f_p$ can absolutely compute $r$ if $r$ is computable for example! Why do you think $f_p\not\ge_Tr$ for every $r$? (As I said, it is true that for *some* $r$ we will have this, assuming $\neg$CH, but this is much weaker.)

Comment: Yes ofc that's false for computable $r$. What I meant was can this be shown to be false/true more generally, when say $r$ encodes the halting problem (or any other set for that matter). And what would be a *specific example* of such an $r$ and $f_p$, so that with access to $f_p$ one can't compute $r$. $f_p$ must eventually dominate every function that one can compute with access to $r$. (also in case there is still some point where I am being ambiguous please do point it out)

Comment: @SSequence Again, I've given lots of specific examples: for **any non-hyperarithmetic $r$** (e.g. [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O)) we can find an appropriate $F$ such that $r$ isn't computable from any of the $f_p$s. By contrast, the halting problem is *never* such an example (since it's hyperarithmetic). Meanwhile, for a *specific* $F$ I don't know what to do, since I don't have a specific $F$ in hand (and can't, in a precise sense: no such $F$ is easily definable!). I'm a bit lost as to what you're claiming at this point.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you have addressed what I asked in the question in the last statement (in the answer).

Comment: Just a small further question. Suppose we denote the set of all increasing functions that are computationally reducible to $r$ as $A_r$. Now suppose that there exists some function $f$ such that $f>A_r$ ($f$ eventually dominates all functions in $A_r$) and yet $f$ can't compute $r$. Is the above true for all non-hyperarithmetic functions $r$ or just some of them?

Comment: (OK I think I am expecting the answer to the question in previous comment as yes ..... true for all non-hyperarithmetic $r$ ..... based on the statement towards the end of answer.)

Comment: Also for the part of my question you quoted, what you wrote is what I intended (I wrote it differently because I was putting it as a possibility of how $\neg CH$ would hold given the assumption $p$ and $q$ to be true) ..... That given $\neg CH$, there will be *some* $r$ which will not be computationally reducible to any function in the hierarchy.

Comment: @SSequence Yup, that's correct (and I've added a line about why such a real exists).