# Extracting an increasing function from a countable collection of subsets (of $\mathbb{N}$)

Tags: reference-request, computability

Another question came to my mind right after the answer to this one ([Specific Question about $\omega_1$ hierarchies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934634)). Sorry if this is too many questions (I will delete this one if it doesn't turn out to be a good question).

Given a countable collection $C$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, is there some informal "method"(or alternatively, are there standard examples) which extracts an increasing function (say $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$) from $C$ such that for all sets in $A \in C$ we have $A \leq_T f$. What I mean is that how much difficult it can be (in general) to extract such a function. Given the answer to the linked question, the rough converse to this (extracting $C$ from a *given* function that grows faster than $f$) certainly doesn't seem possible in any fixed fashion.

But my question is that *given* $C$, is there some method (or at least, standard examples) that extracts the function $f$ in the above paragraph. For example, rather famously, if $C$ denotes halt computable sets we have a somewhat simple procedure to extract this function $f$.

But this question isn't about very small collections $C$, but potentially very broad classes (where $C$, for example, might also contain non-hyperarithmetic sets etc.). Or possibly various collections that possibly turn up in broader definitions of computability.

Or is it the case that extracting such a function is usually too cumbersome/unnatural and doesn't give us any more perspective than what directly what $C$ gives us (even for rather standard examples of $C$).

I understand that this is a broad question (the more examples the better), but also deliberately so.

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to do this, but as far as I know it's generally not useful - as you say, it doesn't tend to give any new information. That said, here's one approach which I'll break into steps. *Below, "set" means "set of natural numbers" and "function" means "function from natural numbers to natural numbers."*

---

First, note that any function can be turned into an increasing function in an information-preserving way: given $f:\omega\rightarrow\omega$, we let $f^{inc}$ be the function defined recursively by $$f^{inc}(0)=f(0),\quad f^{inc}(i+1)=f^{inc}(i)+f(i+1)+1$$ *(the "$+1$" being used to handle the possibility that $f$ outputs $0$; if we dropped it, $f^{inc}$ would only be guaranteed to be nondecreasing)*. It's clear that $f^{inc}$ is increasing and computable from $f$, and given $f^{inc}$ we can compute $f$ recursively by $$f(0)=f^{inc}(0),\quad f(i+1)=f^{inc}(i+1)-f^{inc}(i)-1.$$

---

So it's enough to produce an *arbitrary* function computing each set in $C$ *(note that we may assume for simplicity that $C$ is closed under $\le_T$, since each set only computes countably many sets)*.

But this is easy: given sets $C_i$ ($i\in\omega$), we just let $f(\langle i,j\rangle)=0$ if $j\not\in C_i$ and $f(\langle i,j\rangle)=1$ if $j\in C_i$, where "$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$" is [your favorite computable pairing operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). Clearly $f$ computes each $C_i$, and so we're done.

---

At this point it's worth mentioning an important side fact - that we can never **exactly capture** $C$ this way, except in trivial cases. Specifically:

> **Infinitary least upper bounds in the Turing degrees never exist**. Suppose $S$ is a collection of sets which is $\le_T$-directed (that is,for any finitely many sets $A_1,...,A_n$ in $S$, there is some $B\in S$ such that $B\ge_TA_1,...,A_n$). Then either $S$ has a maximally complicated member (that is, there is some $A\in S$ such that $A\ge_TB$ for all $B\in S$) or **there is no set $X$ such that $$\{Y: Y<_TX\}=\{Y:\exists A\in S(Y\le_TA)\}.$$**

*This is a consequence of the [Exact Pair Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21991/does-the-exact-pair-phenomenon-for-partial-orders-occur-in-your-area-of-mathemat), which is my favorite theorem in computability theory and ruins many lovely hopes and dreams. It's proved by forcing, of course, because forcing makes everything better.*

So given $C$, we produce an $f$, *but* this $f$ will compute lots of things it "shouldn't." Intuitively, we can't collapse an unordered collection *(as opposed to a list)* of sets/functions into a single set/function and preserve the "information-theoretic picture," and this is a big part of why constructions such as the above simply aren't very useful.

Comment: Well, while I haven't read the construction yet, I was suspecting that there would be some way to keep the function $f$ increasing while coding the information of elements of $C$ within it (though honestly, I wasn't clear how to do it). I was hoping that there would be some cool way to give a neat definition of the function $f$ in some cases at least. For example, just like when one gives definition of $BB$ using an ordinary program, *perhaps* there might be some way to do this with a more generic program (say ITRM) while also being able to satisfy the property in question.Anyway...

Comment: @SSequence Well, there is in some cases: if every element of $C$ is computable from $0^{(\alpha)}$ for some computable ordinal $\alpha$ - that is, if the elements of $C$ are hyperarithmetic *of bounded rank* - then we can take $f$ to be the modulus function of $0^{(\alpha)}$, which is the analogue of $BB$. But once we move to more complicated situations, this breaks down.

Comment: By the way, what part of the answer would change (or wouldn't change) significantly, if we also add the condition $f>g$ ($f$ eventually dominates $g$), where $g$ is any arbitrary function satisfying $g \leq_T C$. I am guessing .... not much.

Comment: @SSequence None at all, really. And in fact we could replace $g$ by a truly arbitrary function: the key point is that for every real $x$ and function $g$ there is a function $f$ dominating $g$ and computing $x$. This isn't hard to prove: e.g. take $\hat{f}(i)=2^{g(i)+1}3^{\chi(i)}$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $x$, and let $f=\hat{f}^{inc}$.